# Limit number of concurrent asynchronous xhr requests in javascript - avoid net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, concurrency, xmlhttprequest

I wrote a function to make multiple asynchronous xhr requests to a same domain url and seeing  net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES error in chrome very often. I believe this is because of huge number of requests I'm making, around ~4000.

I need to wait for all the requests to complete and then call a function(func1) passing the results, here is my function

```
function doRequests(totalEntities)
{
  var count = 0;
  var request = new Array(totalEntities);
  var result = new Array(totalEntities);
  for (var i = 0; i < totalEntities; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        request[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request[i].open("GET", uri+"/"+i, true);
        request[i].onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request[i].readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (200 <= request[i].status < 300) {
              result[i] = {
                data: JSON.parse(request[i].responseText)
              }
            } else {
              console.log(request[i].statusText);
            }
            count++;
            if (count > (totalEntities) - 1) func1(result);
          }
        };
        request[i].send();
      }
    }(i));
  }
}
```

How can I get rid of ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES error? How can I make say 10 requests at a time and then wait for them to complete before sending next batch of 10 and so on...?

Comment: Oh! I've just written a whole library that does exactly that (and more), but it is still beta. If you want I can answer by using that library, otherwise, my hint is that you need a queue and to track current active requests. Then call a function each time that a request reaches `readyState === 4`. This function should call the next request in queue and update the active requests set/array. You also have to handle errors and other ugly things.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano Thanks alot. Yes, I would love to see the answer with your library. Also thanks for the alternative idea.

Comment: Nice! Tomorrow I'll publish the latest version and answer your question with a working example.